# Django: Multiple url patterns starting at the root spread across files

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am wondering if it is possible to have the standard url patterns spread across multiple files (in this case the project-wide `urls.py` and several apps-specific `urls.py`).

Imagine that the project `urls.py` look like this (got this working):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user/signup/', 'registration.views.signup'),
    url(r'^user/confirm/(?P<code>\w{20})/', 'registration.views.confirm'),
    url(r'^user/profile/(\d+)/', 'profile.views.show'),
    url(r'^user/profile/edit/', 'profile.views.edit'), 
)
```

As you can see, I have two different apps that both want to user the urls for /user/*, so I can't just use `r'^user/'` with an include.

My question is: Can I split the above into two seperate `urls.py` files, that each go into their respective app?

*Note: Disregard any syntax mistakes as this was typed in*

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Sure. URLs are processed in order, and two includes can have the same prefix - if one doesn't succeed in matching, processing will just move on to the next one.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user/', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^user/', include('profile.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Ah, so I could technically just add `url(r'^$', include('something'))` if I wanted to add urls with various prefixes (imagine user/, profile/ and reset/ in the same app).

Comment: Yes, except without the $ - you don't want it for includes, as it terminates the match.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the hint that this _should_ work. Except that it doesn't when you've set a namespace. My workaround for this is to collect all patterns with the same prefix in one urlpatterns variable and then include it using a namespace.

Comment: @ephes It works for me if you pass namespace as second argument to `include` like iDevFS points out, in his answer

Comment: Can we set same namespace for both `url` ? Like this: `urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user/', include('registration.urls'), namespace="user"),
    url(r'^user/', include('profile.urls'), namespace="user"),
)`

Answer (score 8):

Also i suggest to add a namespace like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user/', include('registration.urls', namespace="registration")),
    url(r'^user/', include('profile.urls', namespace="profile")),
)
```

Comment: what is the namespace for?

Comment: @eugene It makes referencing URLs easier. In this example, if the `registration` app contains the URL defined as `re_path(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register')`, it can be referenced in your Python code using `reverse('registration:register')` or in your templates using `{% url 'registration:register' %}`. Basically, you're giving your URLs and groups of URLs names, rather than typing the whole URL every time and having to go back and edit every single use of the URL when its definition changes.