# Urlpatterns and Django Debug Toolbar

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

I'm reading "Two Scoops of Django".
Namely about multiple settings files and multiple requirements files.

So, it is recommended to separate base.py, local.py and production.py.

And for base.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ("debug_toolbar", )
```

What troubles me is that Django Debug Toolbar also needs some addition to urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#urlconf

That is we should either accept this mix of debug and production notions or separate them into multiple files.

I investigated this question. For example, this link:
[Django: Multiple url patterns starting at the root spread across files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618105/django-multiple-url-patterns-starting-at-the-root-spread-across-files)

But I'm still somehow suspicious.

Could you give me a piece of advice: what is the best practice of how separate this Django Debut Toolbar from production in urlpatterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this approach since you'll only have one URL conf file that will live inside your project root. So the `if settings.DEBUG:` part, inside your project's root `urls.py` file looks fine with me.

However, if you want to completely seperate the `local` and `production` urls, then you could do it this way:

1. Create a python module for `urls` (just as you would do for the settings)
2. Inside that dir, create your `base_urls.py`, `local_urls.py` and `production_urls.py`
3. Inside the `base_urls` you should put the "global" urls that'll be available for both local and production. Inside the `local_urls` put any additional local urls (like `django-debug-toolbar`). And finally, in your production put... eh the production urls. Of course, `local_urls.py` and `production_urls.py` files should have `from .base_urls import *` at the top.
4. After that, you should change the [`ROOT_URL_CONF`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-ROOT_URLCONF) setting inside the `settings/local.py` file to be `"project.urls.local_urls"` and inside the `settings/production.py` file change (again) the [`ROOT_URL_CONF`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-ROOT_URLCONF) setting to `"project.urls.production_urls"`.

Now, you have separate `urls` files, for each environment.